# Formatting date inside a If than statement

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, formatting, date

I am struggling to find an answer on how to format a If then statement in SharePoint 2013 using a calculated column. I need to display the word "Completed" if the date =1/1/1900 or display the date itself

Current Code:

```
  =IF( [GE Internal Report Receipt]="1/1/1900"
         ,"Complete"
         ,TEXT([GE Internal Report Receipt],"dd/MM/yyyy")
     )
```

Currently this displays the date 1/1/1900 in the date format. This should say complete. I am finding if I do a standard If statement =IF([GE Internal Report Receipt]="1/1/1900","Complete",[GE Internal Report Receipt] I get an output of 2 for the date 1/1/1900 and an output of a random number if there is a true date in the field.

Current Code: Almost working with ISBLANK

```
=IF(ISBLANK([GE Internal Report Receipt]),"Missing Date")

=If([GE Internal Report Receipt]=DATE(1900,1,1)
    ,"Complete"
    ,Text([GE Internal Report Receipt],"dd/MM/yyyy"
   )
```

Comment: See my answer below. where it combines it into one Formula. You can't declare two Formulas with *=* into one. Best method is to create your Formulas in Notepad with linebreaks and copy/paste them into SharePoint (SP will take all linebreaks and spaces out)

Comment: PS. When you paste code in StackOverlfow start each line with 4 spaces/or a Tab, that will format them as code instead of text

Answer (score 3):

You have to go the other way around,

Not convert your date to Text but convert the text you use to compare to a Date.

That will also make it safe to use in any language

*provided your field IS a Date field*

```
IF( [GE Internal Report Receipt] = DATE( 1900 , 1 , 1 )  
   ,"Complete"
   ,TEXT([GE Internal Report Receipt],"dd/MM/yyyy")
 )
```

Note that SharePoint Dates are actually numbers starting counting at december 31st 1899
It is the UI/Language settings that converts them to Date representations

`=TEXT( 1 , "dd/MM/yyyy" )`

will output `31/12/1899`

```
january 1st 1900 = 2
january 2nd 1900 = 3
```

etc.

So that Random number you mentioned is the number of days since December 31st 1899

So you *could* do

```
IF( [GE Internal Report Receipt] = 2  
   ,"Complete"
   ,TEXT([GE Internal Report Receipt],"dd/MM/yyyy")
 )
```

But no-one opening up this Formula will understand whats going on

This is also why BLANK dates are 0 in calculations representing **30** December 1899
To test for blank dates you have to use:

```
IF( ISBLANK( [GE Internal Report Receipt] ) 
   ,"Missing date"
   IF( [GE Internal Report Receipt] = DATE( 1900 , 1 , 1 )  
       ,"Complete"
       ,TEXT([GE Internal Report Receipt],"dd/MM/yyyy")
     )
 )
```

All available functions in SharePoint: http://www.viewmaster365.com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

Comment: Danny, This worked great however it has now created a new issue. If the field [GE Internal Report Receipt] is blank, I need the other field to be blank. We use this column for counting. Great explanation by the way.

Comment: see the ISBLANK function to test for blanks.. and then you also might need the AND function to test for multiple conditions

Comment: I made a mistake, corrected the explanation to explain day 1 is the last day of 1899

Comment: Danny, Both pieces are working on their own, however they are not working together. Any thoughts?

Comment: Add your Formulas into your first question

Comment: Danny, Thank you for all your help. Looks like the major issue I was having had to do with a copy and paste of the code from this screen to where I needed it. I dropped it in Notepad, made the edits I needed and was set! Thank you very much.

Comment: If you do loads of Formulas and are comfortable copy/pasting some JavaScript as a Browser Bookmarklet, see: https://github.com/Danny-Engelman/CalcMaster

Answer (score 1):

More than likely the two objects you are comparing in the IF statement are not equal because one is a date the other is text.  Try this:

```
IF(TEXT([GE Internal Report Receipt], "dd/mm/yyyy")="1/1/1900","Complete",TEXT([GE Internal Report Receipt],"dd/MM/yyyy"))
```

That should make the date object into text so the comparison is apples to apples.

Comment: Sharepoint took the string, however it did not work out just yet. I plugged that in and ended up with the date 1/1/1900 for a final output. I am wondering if there is something wrong with the part ,"complete", since it should be the true value and this is taking the false value.

Comment: I have verified it is officially pulling the false value and not just pulling the date ahead. The [GE Internal Report Receipt] column

Comment: What if I were to reformat the [GE Internal Report Receipt] column for a default value of text? Would that do the trick? If so what is that string, what I am putting in doesnt seem to take.

Comment: One thing you might double check is if the [GE Internal Report Receipt] is a date column that is formatted dd/mm/yyyy.   The next would be to just output the text value for the column (e.g.  TEXT([GE Internal Report Receipt], "dd/mm/yyyy") ) just to see what the text value is.

Comment: What do you mean by false value?

Comment: From how I understand If then statements is =IF(logical_test,value_if_true,value_if_false)

Comment: The comment below fixed this issue but brought up a new one. Please see below if you have time to help me out. I would like to keep it all together. Thank you